# Unraveling the Mysteries of VPS Deployment: Seeking Expertise to Overcome Challenges

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nginx, deployment, vps

In this project, I have encountered several issues. First, let me provide an overview of what I have done so far. I successfully installed Node.js, PostgreSQL, and implemented UFW firewall protection on my VPS machine. Additionally, I set up the Nginx default file for sites-available.

Currently, I can access my frontend application through my browser. I can see that my index.js file is being hosted and interact with it. However, when attempting to utilize features in my app that involve GET or POST requests, such as the registration functionality, specifically through my main domain that already has an HTTPS certificate from Let's Encrypt and displays a locked lock icon, I encounter an issue. For example, here is the URL: https://someDomainName/registration.

Strangely, when I perform the same actions, like attempting registration, using my VPS public IP address in the browser (http://someIPaddress/registration), everything works as intended. I can interact with the backend of my app, register users, and sign in successfully.

My question is, how is it possible for both cases to work, allowing me to interact with them, but when specifically trying to interact with my main domain in the browser (https://someDomainName/registration), I receive a 405 code (Not Allowed) in the console.log of the development tools?

This is my first project, and it was running smoothly on my local machine. However, as soon as I attempted to deploy it, the project started encountering these issues. I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance you can provide. Thank you in advance for your help.

I tried to change proxy_pass, tried different ways, tried to use my VPS's machine IP adress as a proxy_pass.
Tried to seek an error in my database , it seems to work as intended.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for replying to my problem. I figured out the issue, it was a wrong Nginx default file configuration. I had 2 blocks of servers, One was taking requests from regular www.sample.com sample.com and redirecting it to my hmtl react file, and the other was port 443 the https port that was causing troubles, and I forgot to add the my /api redirection therefore my cors() was not allowing such request, so the problem was just a lack of one line of code such as 
location /api {
proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
}
I had this part written in my first block but not in 443 port. That's it =)